# How to create HTML element which takes value from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying create a new element with jQuery which takes its value from a previously defined variable. I cannot find anywhere the code to pass a JS variable as a value when creating the HTML element.

```
<div id="productDiv">
</div>

<script>
     class product {
            constructor(name, price) {
                this.name = name;
                this.price = price;
            }
    
            returnName() {
                return this.name; 
            }
    
            returnPrice() {
                return this.price;
            }  
        }
        
    let product1 = new product("Laptop", 1000);
    
    var myProduct = product1.returnName();
     
    function displayProduct() {
            $('<h id="productName" >#myProduct</h>').appendTo('#productDiv'); //How to add the value here?
        }

</script>
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: `$('<h>').attr('id','productName').text('value goes here').appendTo('#productDiv');`

Comment: <h> has the value of "Laptop" not #myProduct

Comment: You are using a wrong HTML tag, try with some valid heading like <h1>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a parameter to the function for the name and use string concatenation or a template literal.

Note that you should be using an actual HTML tag, e.g. `<h1>`.

```
function displayProduct(name) {
  $('<h id="productName">'+name+'</h>').appendTo('#productDiv');
}
displayProduct(myProduct);
```

```js
class product {
  constructor(name, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }

  returnName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  returnPrice() {
    return this.price;
  }
}

let product1 = new product("Laptop", 1000);

var myProduct = product1.returnName();

function displayProduct(name) {
  $('<h id="productName">' + name + '</h>').appendTo('#productDiv');
}
displayProduct(myProduct);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="productDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: @EKrol Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [literal template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to bind a variable into a string like that

```
const displayProduct = (name) => {
  $(`<h1 id="${name}">${name}</h1>`).appendTo('#productDiv');
}

displayProduct(myProduct);
```